# Width 100% isn't working with overflow: auto;

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, hidden

I'm having issues having a line of text be hidden by it's parent element. I want it to be dynamic in it's width, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

```
.container {  
  border: 6px solid black;  
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
 
}

.die_results {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;    

}

.low_rolls_container {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 100%;  
  overflow: auto;
}

.low_rolls {
  border: 2px solid red;
  font-size: 5rem;
  padding: 2px 5px 0 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="die_results">
    <div class="low_rolls_container">
      <div class="low_rolls">1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13</div>
    </div>
    <div class="high_roll">23</div>
  </div>
  <div class="die_results">
    <div class="low_rolls_container">
      <div class="low_rolls">1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13</div>
    </div>
    <div class="high_roll">23</div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the Red border box to scroll within the blue border box, all while having the width of "container" and "die_results" be dynamic. Is it possible to do this without using a fixed width somewhere?

Comment: At what point should the content start overflowing? At `100px` width? If so, I don't see what's wrong with your code.

Comment: I was going to mention, @SigurdMazanti I can get it to work with a fixed width, but the "low_rolls_container" should be fluid. When the "low_rolls" numbers hit the width of "low_rolls_container", they should be hidden and then able to scroll. The numbers in there are placeholders, and the string could be longer.

Comment: @SigurdMazantiI I also update the CSS to what I would like (the width: 100px was a trial on my end to see if it would scroll, which it would). The updated text is now the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `container` represents any container whatsoever, the fixed width value of `100px` doesn't really matter as the container's width can be fluid and this solution will still work.

I think you've overcomplicated your issue a bit, you've used the correct properties but there's probably been some complications with some of the other properties you've applied.

Using `overflow: auto` on the container thats holding the content that will overflow will only show a scrollbar if the content inside is actually overflowing, not a static scrollbar as if you were using `overflow: scroll`.

The `border` that you see is around the `low_rolls`-element so you can see when it's overflowing.

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
}

.containertwo {
  width: 100%;
}


/* flex for demo purpose, not necessary */
.die_results {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}


/* force scroll on overflow */
.low_rolls_container {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.low_rolls {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: .7rem;
  padding: 2px 5px 0 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="die_results">
    <div class="low_rolls_container">
      <div class="low_rolls">1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 3, 6, 5, 5, 7, 9, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 3, 6, 5, 5, 7, 9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="high_roll">23</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container containertwo">
  <div class="die_results">
    <div class="low_rolls_container">
      <div class="low_rolls">1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 3, 6, 5, 5, 7, 9, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 3, 6, 5, 5, 7, 9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="high_roll">23</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @sigurd, however I don't think it solves my issue. I've updated my example with your example to hopefully better illustrate/clarify the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution below. Needed overflow: hidden; on the container as well.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.die_results {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.low_rolls_container {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.low_rolls {
  border: 2px solid red;
  font-size: 5rem;
  padding: 2px 5px 0 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="die_results">
      <div class="low_rolls_container">
         <div class="low_rolls">1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13</div>
      </div>
      <div class="high_roll">23</div>
   </div>
   <div class="die_results">
      <div class="low_rolls_container">
         <div class="low_rolls">1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13</div>
      </div>
      <div class="high_roll">23</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to see you solved your problem, I don't see whats different between your solution and the one I proposed though.

Comment: @SigurdMazanti The container holding the numbers needed to be fluid as well, which your solution didn't address since it had a fixed width of 100px on the container. I was looking for a responsive solution.  When you compare your code to mine, expand and shrink your browser window and you will see the difference. Hope this helps.

Comment: The width values were for demonstrational purposes, as was stated in the very first paragraph..

Comment: Yeah, I understood that, but you gave a solution to a problem I wasn't having. If you look at the main question I posted, it wasn't working with width: 100%; not width: 100px;. Perhaps it was in my using of "dynamic" instead of "responsive" that added confusion.